# Android access other application method?

Tags: android, android-service

I want to create "plugin" for my main application. This plugin will expose only one method:

```
String getData(String param1, String param2);
```

This method will connect to the webserver and download data. I don't want to place this code in the main app.

How should achieve this? Should I use remote services (https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/AdvServices/) or there is other (better) solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

You can implement your own [Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)

Comment: I don't think that this is good solution. ContentProvider is designed for tables (ex. SQLite) I am not sure if it will be working ok with webservice :>

Answer (score 0):

As @fardjad said, it could be a ContentProvider but also an exported service. But just to clarify, you want your app to expose this service to other apps, right ?

Comment: Yes, I want expose this service to other apps.

Comment: So that's the way to go. Exposing a ContentProvider can be handy. Exposing a service as well. Where does your data come from ?

Comment: My data will come from the web. Do you still recommend ContentProvider :>?